# Sqlalchemy duplicate entry when creating entries dynamically

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

In my application, I am using SQLAlchemy (via MySQL) with Flask, and in my current situation I need to create entries dynamically.  For example, while creating an instance from table A, my script will see that we need to create a related entry B, so after creating B, it will attempt to assign B to one of the relationship attributes of the instance for A.

Here are some example models:

```
a_b = db.Table('a_b',
               db.Column('a_id', db.Integer,
                         db.ForeignKey('a.id',
                                       onupdate="CASCADE",
                                       ondelete="CASCADE"),
                         primary_key=True),
               db.Column('b_id', db.Integer,
                         db.ForeignKey('b.id',
                                       onupdate="CASCADE",
                                       ondelete="CASCADE"),
                         primary_key=True))

class ModelA(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    model_bs = db.relationship('ModelB', secondary=a_b,
                               back_populates='model_as')

class ModelB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    model_as = db.relationship('ModelA', secondary=a_b,
                               back_populates='model_bs')
```

The problem I'm running into is an SQL duplicate entry exception, after running something like this:

```
from base import db
from base.database.models.models import ModelA, ModelB


def creation_test():
    with db.session.no_autoflush:
        # Start creating A
        a = ModelA()
        a.name = 'A Example'

        # See that we need B, so create B
        b = ModelB()
        b.name = 'B Example'
        b.model_as = []
        db.session.add(b)
        db.session.flush((b,))

        # Use B in the relationship from A
        a.model_bs = [b]
        db.session.add(a)
        db.session.flush((a,))

    db.session.commit()

creation_test()
```

It will spit out an exception like:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO a_b (a_id, b_id) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (1L, 1L)]
```

Is there something wrong with how the entries are being added to the session and/or how they are being flushed?  Is it even possible to instantiate entries like this?

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my version of SQLAlchemy and testing a few things, it seemed like I was able to solve this by removing the flushes in between creating each instance, and instead just perform a single flush before committing the session:

```
from base import db
from base.database.models.models import ModelA, ModelB


def creation_test():
    with db.session.no_autoflush:
        # Start creating A
        a = ModelA()
        a.name = 'A Example'

        # See that we need B, so create B
        b = ModelB()
        b.name = 'B Example'
        b.model_as = []
        db.session.add(b)

        # Use B in the relationship from A
        a.model_bs = [b]
        db.session.add(a)

    db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()

creation_test()
```